# hash table internal index

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashtable

How can I reach the internal array representation of the Java Hashtable?  I know that hashtables are just cleverly organized arrays and I want to use the index of each key so I can work in parallel with a Disjoint set.

I need one of two things:

1. The hash function used to turn my keys into the index in the internal array of the hashtable
2. The corresponding index of the key.

Comment: I think if you need to such stuff you better use your own implementation of hash table. Or copy existing one from somewhere and use it. Because if you use some third party or standard class there is a probability that it's inner implementation will change and you program will crash.

Comment: Ok yea, I was just busy and was hoping I could get around rewriting one of my hashtables.  Thanks anyway everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Note 1: In 90% of the cases you should probably use the [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) class instead of [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

Note 2: Actually most hash tables combine a *list* with an array, in order to handle hash collisions.

In general you are *not* supposed to be able to reach the internals of the classes that come with the Java implementation. That would defeat the whole purpose of Java providing the ability for a clear separation between interface and implementation.

I would suggest, instead, that you create a new class e.g. `MyHashMap` by copying over the source code of the `HashMap` implementation from your Java Development Kit. By having your own copy you have full control and you are not subject to unexpected breakage after a JRE update. You can find the OpenJDK `HashMap` implementation [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html).

PS: You *could* theoretically try accessing the `HashMap` internals using reflection, but the resulting code would be *atrocious* and the performance even worse...

Comment: What is the benefit of hashmaps? I just haven't learned about them.

Comment: @BenKellman: Internally the two classes are very similar - the major difference is that `Hashtable` is synchronized, which usually means a rather unwanted overhead. It is also quite a bit older, which means that its interface is relatively cluttered with interfaces that are not used by newer classes any more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can access any field with reflection just take a look on Hashtable internals.

Or you simply looking for code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Create a hashtable-like class that alphabetically assigns indices to keys. Extending HashMap or something like that is for your purposes probably not even necessary. It will be fun.